# Method in objective-c never called

Tags: objective-c

I've got this class.

.h:

```
#import 

@class GLEngine;

@interface opengl_engineAppDelegate : NSObject  {

    // Pointer to engine
    GLEngine * myGLEngine;

    UIWindow * window;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet GLEngine * myGLEngine;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow * window;

@end
```

Here is .m:

```
#import "opengl_engineAppDelegate.h"
#import "GLEngine.h"

@implementation opengl_engineAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize myGLEngine;

// Creating Application
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [myGLEngine activateEngine];
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [myGLEngine activateEngine];
}

// Destroying Application
- (void)dealloc {

    [window release];
    [myGLEngine release];

    [super dealloc];

}


@end
```

And GLEngine looks like:

```
#import 
#import 
#import 
#import 
#import 
#import 

@interface GLEngine : UIView {


}

- (void)activateEngine;

@end
```

Why activateEngine never calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are never allocing myGLEngine or setting it to anything.  You should set a breakpoint at the activateEngine call and check that myGLEngine is actually the object you think it is.

Comment: I've created null project from SDK with the same code - it works X_X.

Comment: That project likely contains more code than is show here.   Did you set the breakpoint in the non-working code and examine the ivars?

Comment: I've cleaned all the code - object is not initializing... Also i've got the same (!) code from sdk - and it works... What is that?

Comment: Really - i've got copypasted code - in one project (OpenGL ES) it works, and in clean project - it doesn't. Frameworks included are the same. And i don't use OpenGL, i still want instance of class)